# Removing an instance from a linked list which is using pairs

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to remove an instance from my linked list however when i try searching for the object in the list it returns a value of -1 because it says its not there. what  am i doing wrong. my application class is below and that calls the methods in my DataSet class

```java
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DataSet<String, Integer> db = new DataSet<>();


        db.add("Theo", 4);
        db.add("Maria", 5);
        db.add("Adam", 4);
        db.add("James", 5);
        db.add("Charles", 7);
        db.add("Nikki", 5);
        db.add("Lynne", 5);
        db.add("Kendal", 6);
        db.add("Kerry", 5);
        db.add("Janet", 5);
        db.add("Gordon", 6);
        db.add("Stepher", 7);
        db.add("Sue", 3);
        db.add("Ed", 2);
        db.add("Adam", 4);


        db.displayItems();
  /*      
        System.out.println();

        db.sortByFirst();
        db.displayItems();

        System.out.println();

        db.sortBySecond();
        db.displayItems();

        System.out.println();

        (db.findBySecond(5)).displayItems();

        System.out.println();

       (db.findByFirst("Adam")).displayItems();

        System.out.println();

       */ System.out.println(db.remove("Adam", 4));
        db.displayItems();
        //System.out.println("size = " + db.size());

    }

}
```

and the dataset is:

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;


/**
 *
 * @param <T>
 * @param <S>
 */
public class DataSet<T, S> {

    LinkedList<Pair> datastructure = new LinkedList<>();
// Adds a new instance/item to the data structure.

    public void add(T first, S second) {
        Pair p = new Pair(first, second);
        datastructure.add(p);
    }
    // Displays all itmes in the data structure.

    public void displayItems() {

        for (int i = 0; i < datastructure.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(datastructure.get(i));
        }
    }
    // Removes all instances with matching criteria (first and second attribute values) and returns the number of instances removed.

    public int remove(T first, S second) {
        int count = 0;
        Pair p = new Pair(first, second);

        for (Pair datastructure1 : datastructure) {
            Integer num = datastructure.indexOf(p);
            System.out.println(num);
            Boolean removed = datastructure.remove(p);
            System.out.println(removed);
        }

        //will return count of how many removed
        return count;
    }

}
```

and the final class is the pair class

```java
class Pair<T,S> {

     private T first;
    private S second;

    public Pair(T theFirst, S theSecond) {
        first = theFirst;
        second = theSecond;
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public S getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + first + ", " + second + ")";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int remove(T first, S second) {
        int count = 0;
        Pair p = new Pair(first, second);

        for (Pair datastructure1 : datastructure) {
            Integer num = datastructure.indexOf(p);
            System.out.println(num);
            Boolean removed = datastructure.remove(p);
            System.out.println(removed);
        }

        //will return count of how many removed
        return count;
    }
```

In above remove method, you are creating a new `Pair` object. New object means new reference, So `datastructure.indexOf(p)` will always result -1.

```
Example:
datastructure contains three pairs:
Pair1 - reference 0x00000001 - "Theo",4
Pair2 - reference 0x00000002 - "Theo",5
Pair3 - reference 0x00000003 - "Theo",6 

And we asked to remove "Theo",4. So `p` will be a new object like:
p - reference 0x00000004 - "Theo",4
```

This means that the reference of `p` will not match and it will not check the data. Modify the equals method of `Pair` class as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(obj instanceof Pair)
        {
            Pair pair = (Pair)obj;
            if(pair.first.equals(this.first) && pair.second.equals(this.second)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Adam pointed out the problem is that you're creating a new pair that is not in the list. What you want to do is to create an equals method in your Pair class and then iterate through your list comparing the elements using this equals method. The method should look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Pair other = (Pair) obj;
    if (this.first != other.first) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.second != other.second) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```